# How to plot this 3D ParametricRegion?

Tags: plotting, regions, parametric-functions

I want to plot this 3D `ParametricRegion` by using `Region`,

```
Clear["Global`*"]; reg = 
 ParametricRegion[{{1 + (1 - 4 t) UnitStep[1/2 - t, -(1/4) + t] - 
     UnitStep[
      1 - t, -(3/4) + t], (-1 + 4 t) UnitStep[
       1/2 - t, -(1/4) + t] + (4 - 4 t) UnitStep[
       1 - t, -(3/4) + t], (-3 + 4 t) UnitStep[1 - t, -(3/4) + t]}, 
   0 <= t <= 1}, {t}];
Region[reg, PlotRange -> {{-1, 2}, {-1, 2}, {-1, 2}}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> True, Frame -> False, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
 BaseStyle -> {Red, Thick}]
```

> Returns unevaluated after a `Region::nonopt` warning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, the `Frame->False` option should be taken away, as mentioned in the document, this is an option for 2D plot. (I'd argue that `Region` should have spit out a more instructive warning message, though. ) Sadly, after correcting this, `Region` still cannot handle the `reg` properly. A possible work-around is to first convert to an implicit region and discretize:

```
reg = ParametricRegion[{{1 + (1 - 4 t) UnitStep[1/2 - t, -(1/4) + t] - 
       UnitStep[1 - t, -(3/4) + t], (-1 + 4 t) UnitStep[
         1/2 - t, -(1/4) + t] + (4 - 4 t) UnitStep[1 - t, -(3/4) + t], (-3 + 
         4 t) UnitStep[1 - t, -(3/4) + t]}, 0 < t < 1}, t] // 
   RegionConvert[#, "Implicit"] & // DiscretizeRegion

Region[reg, PlotRange -> {{-1, 2}, {-1, 2}, {-1, 2}}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, BaseStyle -> {Red, Thick}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

```
ParametricPlot3D[{1 + (1 - 4 t) UnitStep[1/2 - t, -(1/4) + t] - 
   UnitStep[
    1 - t, -(3/4) + t], (-1 + 4 t) UnitStep[
     1/2 - t, -(1/4) + t] + (4 - 4 t) UnitStep[
     1 - t, -(3/4) + t], (-3 + 4 t) UnitStep[1 - t, -(3/4) + t]}, {t, 
  0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: `f[t_] = RegionConvert[Line[{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}], 
     "Parametric"] /. \[FormalX] -> t // First // First`